# search replace with exception of quotes

Tags: linux, text-formatting

I have the following text that I need to replace all the whitespace with linefeed except anything in quotes.

**INPUT**

```
This is an example text with    some      spaces.
This should be 2nd line.
However the spaces between "quotes    should not    change".
last line
```

The output should look likes this:

```
This
is
an
example
text
with    
some
spaces.
This
should
be
2nd
line.
However
the
spaces
between
"quotes    should not    change".
last
line
```

I tried to use awk/sed/perl but can't figure out to put except for quotes.

The quoted text will not span more than one line.

Comment: Could quoted text span more than one line?

Comment: no, they do not. good question

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** My solution was total overkill. I don't know what I was thinking. The problem can be solved by an extremely simple regular expression. See [the solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405107/search-replace-with-exception-of-quotes/405141#405141) submitted by [JJoao](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/96276/jjoao).

---

The Python `shlex` library *almost* does this out-of-the-box. Here's an example script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""tokens.py"""

import sys
import shlex

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as textfile:
    text = ''.join(textfile.readlines())
    for token in shlex.split(text, posix=False):
        print(token)
```

If your data is in the file `data.txt` (for example) then you could run it like this:

```bsh
python tokens.py data.txt
```

And here is the output it produces:

```
This
is
an
example
text
with
some
spaces.
This
should
be
2nd
line.
However
the
spaces
between
"quotes    should not    change"
.
last
line
```

Notice that it puts the period on a separate line. This is because it ends tokens at closing-quotes. Since the example you gave doesn't seem to require multiline strings or escaped characters, it's probably not to hard to roll your own little lexer. Here's what I came up with:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""tokens.py"""

import sys

def tokenize(string):
    """Break a string into tokens using white-space as the only delimiter
    while respecting double-quoted substrings and keeping the double-quote
    characters in the resulting token."""

    # List to store the resulting list of tokens
    tokens = []

    # List to store characters as we build the current token
    token = []

    # Flag to keep track of whether or not
    # we're currently in a quoted substring
    quoted = False

    # Iterate through the string one character at a time
    for character in string:

        # If the character is a space then we either end the current
        # token (if quoted is False) or add the space to the current
        # token (if quoted is True)
        if character == ' ':
            if quoted:
                token.append(character)
            elif token:
                tokens.append(''.join(token))
                token = []

        # A double-quote character is always added to the token
        # It also toggles the 'quoted' flag
        elif character == '"':
            token.append(character)
            if quoted:
                quoted = False
            else:
                quoted = True

        # All other characters are added to the token
        else:
            token.append(character)

    # Whatever is left at the end becomes another token
    if token:
        tokens.append(''.join(token))

    # Return the resulting list of strings
    return(tokens)

if __name__=="__main__":
    """Read in text from a file and pring out the resulting tokens."""
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as textfile:
        text = ''.join(textfile.readlines()).replace("\n", " ")
        for token in tokenize(text):
            print(token)
```

This produces exactly the results you asked for. You could probably implement this algorithm in another language (like Perl) pretty easily. I just happen to be more comfortable with Python.

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU-grep:

```
grep -Po '(".*?"|\S)+' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If empty lines from the original text can be removed:

```
sed -r 's/("[^"]*"[^ ]?)/\n\1\n/g' input.txt |
sed -r '/^"/!s/\s{1,}/\n/g' |
sed '/^$/d'
```

If empty lines from the original text should be preserved:

```
sed -r 's/("[^"]*"[^ ]?)/###\n\1\n###/g' input.txt |
sed -r '/^"/!s/\s{1,}/\n/g' |
sed '/###/d'
```

**Input** (complicated for the testing)

```
This is an "example text" with    some      spaces.
This should be 2nd line.
"However the spaces" between "quotes    should not    change".
"last line"
```

**Output**

```
This
is
an
"example text"
with
some
spaces.
This
should
be
2nd
line.
"However the spaces"
between
"quotes    should not    change".
"last line"
```